# What research suggests that people grasp information better when arranged in groups of three?

Tags: communication

The author didn't cite any source for this "Research into communications theory".

> Why should you aim for two or three major points? Research into
> communications theory suggests that people grasp information better
> when it is arranged in groups of three. While you need not adhere
> to this rule slavishly, a three-tiered argument gives the appearance
> of balance and strength.7 In addition, it is unlikely that all seven or
> eight points will really stand alone: no fact pattern is that complex.
> It is much more likely that some of those points can be combined
> in some way and those that cannot are either mere spectres or too
> minor to merit a mention.

Page 17. Stacie Strong [BA English literature (UC Davis 1986), MPW (USC 1990), JD (Duke 1994), PhD Law (Cambridge 2002), DPhil (Oxford 2003)](https://www.linkedin.com/in/s-i-strong-50b82832/). *How to Write Law Essays & Exams* 5th Edition (2018).  p 47.